# How to capture any fields entered by user in java and log into database

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a requirement where need to capture any action (update,modification or insertion) done by user and log into database. Using log4j and writing logs into server but requirement is to insert into log table. Is there any way to capture or any alternate solution of capturing logs to database.

I have written a utility method to capture logs but I feel its pretty inefficient way its being handled.

---

```
public class Logging {   

public static void captureLogs(Logs logs, String action, String userID, Date createdDate) {   
    logs.setUserId(userID);
    logs.setAction(action);
    logs.setCreatedDate(createdDate);

}
}

public class Logs {

 private String action;
 private String userId;
 private Date createdDate;

  // getters and setters

}

@Service   
public TaskServiceImpl implements TaskService {

 private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TaskServiceImpl .class);

 @Autowired   
 private   Logsrepository logsrepository;

 @Autowired    
 private   UserRepository userRepository;

 public String updateUserDetails(String userId,UserDto dto){

 Logs logs=new Logs();    
 Task task=userRepository.findOne(userId);    
 task.setTaskId(dto.getTaskId);    
 task.setTaskCompletedDate(dto.getTaskCompletedDate);    
 String action="User updated taskID"+dto.getTaskId+" and 
 taskCompletedDate"+dto.getTaskCompletedDate;    
 LOGGER.info("message : "+ action);    
 Logging.logs(logs,action,userId,new Date());    
 userRepository.flush();    
 logsrepository.save(logs);    
  }
 }
```

---

Can it be handled in better way?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. My feeling is that you'd want to get log4j to do this for you, and indeed this does seem to be possible - see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_database.htm (though I may have got the wrong end of the stick).

Comment: you could use a trigger

Comment: @Gnk sorry for delay response. Can you help with relative example for triggers. I am not able to get how to capture each field change.

Comment: @MandyShaw using log4j to capture might not satisfy the requirement

Comment: It would be good to know where the requirement overshoots what log4j can provide, since all you have requested in the question is the diversion of your log information to a database table. If you need the data structured differently, you could always just scope a suitable view over the log table, or otherwise manipulate the output.